# Custom array Adatpter on click method

Tags: android

I created custom ArrayAdapter class, but onItemClickListener doesn't work(

WHAT IS THE REASON FOR THAT? I tried to extend Base adapter class, and it works. But why can't I extand ArrayAdapter one?

```
public class ContactsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
    //
//    private final Context context;
//    private final String[] values;
    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Person[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, Person[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Person> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public Person getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Person> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout,parent,false);
        TextView txtName= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_contact);
        //TextView txtSurname= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txtName.setText(getItem(position).name);
        // txtSurname.setText(getItem(position).surname);

        return rowView;


    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inflating an xml file that has focusable views within them, you must make sure that this property is false when using them in a custom adapter.  Try to add this for the EditText (R.id.list_item_contact) in the xml file you are inflating: `android:focusable="false"`